# How to define such a TypeScript generic that traversal the routes config tree and accumulate path

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have

```
type Route = {
  path: string
  children?: readonly Route[]
}

const root = {
  path: "a",
  children: [
    { path: "b" },
    { path: "c", children: [{ path: "d", children: [{ path: "e" }] }] }
  ],
} as const satisfies Route;
```

I want to define a TypeScript generic `Convert` such that output of `Convert<typeof root>` is  string enum 'a' | 'a/b' | 'a/c' | 'a/c/d' | 'a/c/d/e'

`type Convert<T extends Route> = ?`

I tried something like

```
type Convert<T extends Route, Prefix extends string = ''> = 
`${Prefix}/${T['path']}` | (
    T["children"] extends readonly Route[]
      ? {
        [K in number]: Convert<T['children'][K], `${Prefix}/${T['path']}`>;
      }[number]
      : never)
```

but Output = "/a" | "/a/b" | "/a/c" doesn't go deep enough.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2NAvFA3gWAFBSmAQ2AAsAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMc8BjY2gGwBNqJ6A-OT4FucepxCxEyANoBdHAF8cOVuKpRqcOMChosufETJQARATMAaFlHZde-crNt50xkuTMAjM1CU2Rm4epmas1nYcPHz0zu6EnubcEfbRTlCy8SZeEH5K8v4FKkbygUpQBBR2GnoURLQUAGa0EFXwSBAA3KrYoJBQAKIAHpCsemgA5AQTUAA+UFMA9N4z80vei6yrCwTLm4vc2+v73IsQEz190ADC4gBuENTAADwAKlAQQ8j03G0yEFYoAAFPjNIYfL78X6UGgMRj6BYTAB8CJwAAMACToEEQMFKRZY16yCYJYgTeRKNFzKAAClcUCJYSijnoZgKn2+0JEYgkUnackUQTwUAEGHpwoyAGkoAwoPQEABbbyPeTkW70B5PN7E1Is8mySWlKCY7Gg2hDfGE4mk8mUpHdIV4JSyeVKlXiqDkegQTUASku4Ggw0IP2eAA0UWgwxDOVUEPQANb0OAAd3oIqg0a9PseDquUAA8kgwEgEcGCKH1ZqXlc4I0tDpgEikUA

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are undoubtedly many ways to go about this.  Here's one:

```
type Convert<T extends Route> =
  T['path'] | (
    T extends { children: readonly (infer R extends Route)[] } ?
    `${T['path']}/${Convert<R>}` : never
  );
```

All I'm doing there is outputting the `path` property, and recursively grabbing `R`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `Route`s in the `children` property, and applying `Convert<R>`... and appending that to the `path` property with a slash.

Let's make sure it works:

```
type Expect = 'a' | 'a/b' | 'a/b/c' | 'a/b/c/d' | 'a/b/c/d/e'
type Actual = Convert<typeof root>;
// type Actual = "a" | "a/b" | "a/c" | "a/c/d" | "a/c/d/e"
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2NAvFA3gWAFBSmAQ2AAsAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMc8BjY2gGwBNqJ6A-OT4FucepxCxEyANoBdHAF8cOVuKpRqcOMChosufETJQARATMAaFlHZde-crNt50xkuTMAjM1CU2Rm4epmas1nYcPHz0zu6EnubcEfbRTlCy8SZeEH5K8v4FKkbygUpQBBR2GnoURLQUAGa0EFXwSBAA3KrYOKCQUADC4gBuENTAADwAKlAQAB7I9NxtMhAAfPq207IA5AnEuwUAPlAAFK5QswtLKxiRDjHCEKLikucMjeOwc4v8d+1kABKBT+KACS4AAwAJOgdvsTEclAB6WHDehjCaTGDrJSQqDkegQTG2IHdXrYfrQACi80grD0aF2BF2UFOzOR3lZ7IInORrG5UA53n5yO4guFou4yIguz64GgAEEGQgCJx9ENRuMplS4I0tDpgOtycjkVAqVBlcBVeq0BY-KcLJyHeZeeE2a6pS6nawxTKzEA)

Comment: thank you, very elegant solution! I'm wondering why my approach didn't work, I expect the `{ ... }[number]` part gives me the output for the child route, then I construct recursively to get the final output

Comment: `K in number` doesn't iterate over anything; it just gives `K` as `number`.  So you're probably getting the union all at once, and if your type doesn't distribute across unions, you probably lose information you care about.  It's probably out of scope to do a deep dive into the ways your approach didn't work.